# Is there a way to autostart a user session without logging in?

Tags: lightdm, users, autostart

I am administering a hybrid server/workstation using Ubuntu 12.04. There are several users that have access to the PC, and it is also working as a simplified fileserver using samba. This fileserver is associated to an account, which also has a Dropbox account where certain folders are synchronized for remote (outside the local network) access.

I would like that the "server" user session to be started automatically, but without logging in to the desktop. In other words, I would like that the first screen showed after booting is LightDM, but with one account already started (and protected by a password).

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Tell us why a specific user must be loged in but with a locked screen? i.e. example if you use a command via ssh you will exec the comands as a specific user witout beeing loged in. The WS must only run into the login-screen an the system is usable via ssh.

Comment: The main reason is Dropbox. I need to autostart the Dropbox daemon that is user-specific. I tried some tutorials I found in internet, but they appear to be only for Ubuntu server, and they don't seem to work in my configuration.

Comment: `but they appear to be only for Ubuntu server, and they don't seem to work in my configuration.` that sounds fishy. A daemon (for dropbox) does not care about a desktop.  You should be able to do what you want without logging in.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to auto-login in the session and let execute a script on startup wich locks the screen in a few seconds. Probably not best practice, but the login is the start of a session, so I don't think you can start the session without a login.