# Upon reboot, can GUI applications be started in an X session without ever having the screen unlocked?

Tags: login, desktop-environments, lock-screen

I have a home server.  Sometimes, I have to reboot it from a distance, or it reboots itself, say after a power failure.  I would like that some GUI applications to be started under my user, immediately upon reboot.  But, as a home server, I do not want my kids to get access to my account, ever.  I want the screen to remain always locked, booting up the X Session and GUI applications in the background.

Once I get home, I can login into my account in the already booted up X Session and see all my GUI applications up and running.

Is this possible, or should I open a feature request?

Comment: This question is related to the question '[Is there a way to autostart a user session without logging in?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/259774/is-there-a-way-to-autostart-a-user-session-without-logging-in)'.

Answer (score 1):

Add `gnome-screensaver-command -l` as one of your Startup Applications commands

Alternatively, create the file `.config/autostart/lockScreen.desktop` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=lockScreen
Exec=gnome-screensaver-command -l
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

The idea is the same in both cases.

Comment: It's tricky, nice :)

Comment: 'Add gnome-screensaver-command -l as one of your Startup Applications commands'.  You would need to be more specific.  Where are the Startup Application commands?

Also, I tried the lockScreen.desktop solution and that does not work.  The application are started only once I login manually on the computer, as expected.